# Adding file path from options in Command line argument(Python)

Tags: python, automation, argv, sys

Im trying to call a script to run some commands in remote dev server with this path.

Sample code for dev server

```
def funcA():
     
        if os.path.exists("/opt/dev/bin"):
            process = subprocess.run(["ls", "****" , "*****"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        else:
            print("the path doesnt exist")
            sys.exit(2)
```

When i run it it works fine. I want to modify the script in such a way that i can check paths in different environment

I tried this

```
def funcA():
    path=sys.argv[1]


 if os.path.exists(path):
            process = subprocess.run(["ls", "****" , "*****"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        else:
            print("the path doesnt exist")
            sys.exit(2)

i add the path as argument it works fine. 

sample.py /opt/prod/bin
```

Is there a better way to do this ?   instead of entering the whole path  as argument such as asking the user which environment(prod,test etc) and updating the path accordingly ?

Comment: `environment = input('Environment: '); mypath = pathlib.Path.joinpath(pathlib.Path('/opt', environment, 'bin')`

Comment: Its automated. i dont want to manually provide input.

Comment: The last sentence in your question sounds like you are looking for a way to use user input ("asking the user"). You should edit and clarify your question to include all the information someone needs to create an answer. My suggestion isn't exclusively tied to using `input`. You could set environment in a loop: `environments = ['prod', 'test']; for environment in environments` or read them from a file or the environment. What is it that you're really trying to do? What are the starting conditions and constraints? What result are you expecting? Without complete specifications we can only guess.